# Sidebar обрезается при разных условиях

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Вопрос по сайдбару, задаю `min-height: 100%`; то, вкладка с рецептами растягивает корректно,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но на вкладке с таблицей, сайдбар обрезается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ок, не вопрос, задаю высоту `min-height: 100vh` тогда все наоборот
на вкладке с таблицей сайдбар не обрезается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но, на вкладке с рецептами уже обрезается))) И как сделать, чтоб на всех страницах сайдбар растягивался до низа, ума не приложу)))
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<template>
  <el-col :span="4" v-if="infoCurrentUser && isAuthenticated">
    <el-menu
      default-active="1"
      class="sidebar-menu"
      background-color="#1f1d2b"
      text-color="#fff"
      active-text-color="#fff"
    >
      <div class="profile-info">
        <img
          v-if="infoCurrentUser.imageData"
          class="profile-info__avatar"
          :src="infoCurrentUser.imageData"
          alt="avatar"
        />
        <img
          v-else-if="infoCurrentUser.gender === 'мужской'"
          class="profile-info__avatar"
          src="../assets/img/icons/avatar-man.jpg"
          alt="avatar"
        />
        <img
          v-else
          class="profile-info__avatar"
          src="../assets/img/icons/avatar-woman.jpg"
          alt="avatar"
        />

        <div class="profile-info__user">
          <template>
            <h3 v-if="infoCurrentUser.name" class="profile-info__user-name">
              {{ infoCurrentUser.name }}
            </h3>
            <h3
              v-if="!infoCurrentUser.name && infoCurrentUser.gender === 'мужской'"
              class="profile-info__user-name"
            >
              Неопознанный кот
            </h3>
            <h3
              v-if="!infoCurrentUser.name && infoCurrentUser.gender === 'женский'"
              class="profile-info__user-name"
            >
              Неопознанная кошка
            </h3>
            <p class="profile-info__user-email">{{ infoCurrentUser.email }}</p>
            <button class="profile-info__user-exit" @click="exitProfile">
              Выйти
              <span style="font-size: 1.3rem">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt profile-info__user-exit-icon"></i>
              </span>
            </button>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
      <el-menu-item
        index="index"
        v-for="(item, index) in menuItems"
        :key="index"
        :class="{ 'active-item': currentIndex === index }"
        @click="
          currentIndex = index;
          $router.push({ name: item.routeName }).catch(()=>{});
        "
      >
        <img
          class="sidebar-menu__icon"
          :src="require(`../assets/img/icons/${item.src}`)"
          :alt="item.alt"
        />
        <span class="sidebar-menu__text">{{ item.text }}</span>
      </el-menu-item>
    </el-menu>
  </el-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentIndex: null,
      menuItems: [
        {
          src: 'search-recipes.png',
          text: 'Поиск рецептов',
          alt: 'search-recipes',
          routeName: 'SearchRecipes',

        },
        {
          src: 'news.png',
          text: 'Интересные новости',
          alt: 'news',
        },
        {
          src: 'my-profile.png',
          text: 'Моя анкета',
          alt: 'my-profile',
          routeName: 'UserProfile',
        },
        {
          src: 'goals.png',
          text: 'Установленные цели',
          alt: 'goals',
          routeName: 'MyGoals',
        },
        {
          src: 'selected-recipes.png',
          text: 'Избранные рецепты',
          alt: 'selected-recipes',
          routeName: 'SelectedRecipes',
        },
        {
          src: 'user-rating.png',
          text: 'Рейтинг пользователей',
          alt: 'user-rating',
          routeName: 'UserRating',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    exitProfile() {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' }).catch(() => {});
      this.$store.commit('CLEAR_USER_UD'); // Очищаем UID
      this.$store.commit('CLEAR_INFO_USER'); // Очищаем информацию о пользователе
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isAuthenticated() {
      return this.$store.state.UserAuth.user.isAuthenticated;
    },
    infoCurrentUser() {
      return this.$store.state.UserInfoDatabase.infoCurrentUser;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.profile-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 40px 0 70px 20px;
  font-family: 'MontserratRegular';
  &__avatar {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 2px solid $color_3;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  &__user {
    margin-left: 10px;
    &-name {
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    &-email {
      font-family: 'MontserratMedium';
      font-size: 14px;
      color: $color_7;
      margin-bottom: 3px;
    }
    &-exit {
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      color: $color_3;
      padding: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      &-icon {
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
    }
  }
}

.sidebar-menu {
  min-height: 100vh;
  &__icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  &__text {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
}

.active-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: $color_11 !important;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
.el-menu-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: все зависит от разметки и стилей, которых мы не видим

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что в первом случае общий родительский блок для сайдбара и главного контентного блока обрезает сайдбар по высоте контентного блока.

Такое ощущение, что во втором случае высота сайдбара всегда устанавливается в 100vh. Возможно, вы указали не `min-height`, а `height` или `max-height`.

Попробуйте добавить сайдбару и контентному блоку просто

```
    min-height: 100vh;
```

без указания других высот.

Или попробуйте растянуть родительский блок по высоте, например

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parent-block {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ничего не помогает( Сделал как Вы написали. Код `sidebarа` разместил в посте

Comment: В родителе стоит 
`body {    
  padding: 0;  
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'MontserratRegular';
  font-size: 16px;  
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  background-color: $color_1;  
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь, тег vue не увидел. Я не разбираюсь в этом фреймворке, могу ошибаться. Я так понял, вы тегу **el-menu** прописали `min-height: 100vh;`. Но у него еще родитель есть **el-col**. Попробуйте ему тоже прописать min-height. Насчет контентного блока, ему тоже прописали min-height? У сайдбара и контентного блока прямой общий родитель - это body или какой-то другой тег?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте у сайдбара

```
position: fixed;
height: 100vh;
```